# Get value from input checkbox tag from bootstrap in .NET

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I'm trying using checkbox from Bootstrap (`devoops.me`) with ASP.NET.

On page I have:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="testme" />some text for checkbox to choose
                <i class="fa fa-square-o"></i>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click"/><br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    </div>
</div>
```

On server side:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HtmlInputCheckBox chk = (HtmlInputCheckBox)this.Form.FindControl("testme");
        if (chk.Checked == true)
        {
            Label1.Text = "YES it's checked";
        }
    }
```

But all I get is null.

I don't want to use jQuery or JavaScript. Is is possible?

Could anybody help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FindControl` searches for the ASP.NET controls. In order to register the checkbox as an asp.net control, provide an id and add the `runat="server"` attribute.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="testme" runat="server" />some text for checkbox to choose
                <i class="fa fa-square-o"></i>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click"/><br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    </div>
</div>
```

The server side code can be simplified as follows:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (testme.Checked == true)
    {
        Label1.Text = "YES it's checked";
    }
}
```

Since the checkbox is a registered control, it is directly accessible in the code behind.

Comment: @Aru I added a snippet for the server side code, this should work

Comment: I've tried and cannot reference to "testme" like You did. It gives me error: Name "testme" doesn't exist in current context.

Comment: @Aru The markup and code behind should be in the same .aspx file. If so, check the designer.cs file, it should have a `protected global::System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputCheckBox testme;` line, add it if missing.

Comment: This line should be added automatically, when you type the `runat="server"` in the .aspx for `testme` control. But, sometimes it does not. You can either add the line manually, or remove and re-add the `<input type="checkbox" id="testme" runat="server" />` control so that it will be added automatically.

Comment: this time: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202318/discussion-between-tasos-k-and-aru).

Comment: I think maybe you're not providing a full code snippet.  Is this HTML snippet inside a GridView or Repeater?  Or potentially a postback issue?  Hopefully you guys resolved it via chat, though.